# Rails not finding classes within modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that Rails has an opinion on what the name of my classes and modules should be. As such, I have tried to cohere with it.
In Rails.root/lib/query_finder directory, I have the following structure:

```
/lib
  /query_finder
    /adapters
      active_record.rb
      mongoid.rb
      base.rb
    /strategies
    base.rb
```

In base.rb, I named my class like so:

```
module QueryFinder
  class Base
  end
end
```

In adapters/base.rb, I named my class like so:

```
module QueryFinder
  module Adapters
    class Base
    end
  end
end
```

In adapters/mongoid.rb, I named my class like so:

```
module QueryFinder
  module Adapters
    class Mongoid
    end
  end
end
```

In adapters/active_record.rb, I named my class like:

```
module QueryFinder
  module Adapters
    class ActiveRecord
    end
  end
end
```

But Rails is unable to find the adapters. I try to grab all the constants:

```
> QueryFinder::Adapters.constants
=> []
```

And it's giving me an empty array. I also added the following to autoload path:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

What might I be doing wrong?

I just want to make a note that I am able to reference the constants and classes like so:

```
QueryFinder::Adapters::Base
 => QueryFinder::Adapters::Base
```

The problem is when I use the constants method, it gives an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is lazy loading.  Rails, in production mode, is usually set up to do lazy loading.  That means that the constants are not actually defined until you reference them: At that time it notices you're referencing an undefined constant, finds the file, and loads it.

If you turned off lazy loading, then you could rely upon .constants to tell you what was available.  But performance would suffer.

Another workaround would be for you to explicitly load the required files.